# PostCSS plugin with magento 2

Tags: magento2, css

i need to use  PostCSS with tailwindcss in my magento 2 store, but i can't @import files from node_modules and can't find information about that. i think it's impossible. maybe you can help me, **i need to include css - library via npm in my magento2**

Answer (score 0):

you can use file package.json.sample in magento root for begin from scratch. Remove dependencies in there or keep that if you want. Add your postcss and tailwind in attribute `dependencies`. After that generate `tailwind.config.js`